# a straight line divides the ellipse into two parts, find the distance between the centers of mass of its parts

Tags: analytic-geometry, ellipsoids

$3x+3y-9=0$ divides the ellipse $\frac{x^2}{25}+\frac{y^2}{4} = 1$ into two parts. Find the distance between the centers of mass of its parts
I realized that I need to make several double integrals, and then calculate the Euclidean distance, but I don’t understand how to make these double integrals

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: I tried to solve it through a system of equations, but something went wrong, I also tried to solve it through the formula for finding the distance between points, but it didn’t work either

Comment: I have a solution to this problem.  But I cannot post it because your question is lacking your effort.  If you edit your question and add as much detail as possible as to what you did and where you're stuck, then I will post my solution.  The rules of this website prevents the community from answering questions without context.